# BLOB as parameter in procedure call in mybatis

Tags: mybatis

This is the call in the `ProductServices.xml`

```
<update id="resetPassword" parameterType="batchReport">
 { call user_account_mng.enc_reset_password(
       #{user_Id,jdbcType=VARCHAR,mode=IN},
   #{encrypted_password,jdbcType=VARCHAR,mode=IN},
   #{usr_id, dbcType=VARCHAR,mode=IN},
    #{salt,jdbcType=VARCHAR,mode=IN},
   #{ret_code,jdbcType=CHAR,mode=OUT},
   #{pgp_encrypted_password,jdbcType=BLOB,mode=IN}
)}
```

Now `BatchReport` is a POJO:
(i have declared an alias for it as batchReport)

```
 public class BatchReport 
 {
private String user_Id;
private String encrypted_password;
private String usr_id;
private String salt;
private String ret_code;
private byte[] pgp_encrypted_password;
public String getUser_Id() {
    return user_Id;
}
public void setUser_Id(String user_Id) {
    this.user_Id = user_Id;
}
public String getEncrypted_password() {
    return encrypted_password;
}
public void setEncrypted_password(String encrypted_password) {
    this.encrypted_password = encrypted_password;
}
public String getUsr_id() {
    return usr_id;
}
public void setUsr_id(String usr_id) {
    this.usr_id = usr_id;
}
public String getSalt() {
    return salt;
}
public void setSalt(String salt) {
    this.salt = salt;
}
public String getRet_code() {
    return ret_code;
}
public void setRet_code(String ret_code) {
    this.ret_code = ret_code;
}
public byte[] getPgp_encrypted_password() {
    return pgp_encrypted_password;
}
public void setPgp_encrypted_password(byte[] pgp_encrypted_password) {
    this.pgp_encrypted_password = pgp_encrypted_password;
}

}
```

My main class is like this :

```
 <BatchReport batchReport = new BatchReport();
   byte[] byteArray =new byte[]{1,2,3};
   batchReport.setUser_Id("CHI");
   batchReport.setEncrypted_password("97D6B45"); 
   batchReport.setSalt("71L");
   batchReport.setPgp_encrypted_password(byteArray);
   String returnCode = productServiceObj.resetPassword(batchReport);
```

i am getting following error:
Error setting null parameter.  Most JDBC drivers require that the JdbcType must be specified for all nullable parameters. Cause: java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column type

#### The error may involve com.example.services.ProductServices.resetPassword-Inline

ProductServices is a class in which the method resetPassword is declared.
Please help me with this BLOB issue.
What should be the jdbcType in the called procedure.
what value should be passed in this pgp_encrypted_password.

Answer (score 0):

Okay I found the solution to the problem now the jdbcType in the query in .xml file remains the same i.e BLOB.
Next the type which gets set for passing in the values is byte[].

So everything remains same as i have covered up .
Error actually existed as the  in .xml file returns an integer indicating the number of rows changed in query and I have given the function return type as String so here goes the solution for the problem it should be of type Object.